# accurev convert from stream number to stream name

Tags: version-control, accurev

In Accurev how to convert from stream number to stream name,
Say I have stream number is 257 how to know the stream name from ?

Answer (score 4):

You can run `accurev show -fx -p <depot_name> streams` and you will get an xml output of streams, including name and number.  In the GUI, you can view the stream browser for your depot in split-pane or detailed mode, and that will also show you stream numbers.

Hope this helps,
~James